# Shared Service and asynchronous data in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have a problem with getting data via Shared Service

I have a `Shared Service`

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  public title;
  constructor() {
    this.title = "";
  }

  public setData(val: string): void {
    this.title = val;
  }

  public getUrlHistoryObj(): string {
    return this.title;
  }
}
```

A component `FillComponent` in which I get data from DataService (it works, it gets data and it actually sets data, tested it with console.log)

```
export class FillComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() title: any;
  constructor(public info: InfoComponent, public shared: SharedService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shared.setData(this.title); }
}
```

I get data from `PartComponent`

```
export class Part2Component implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(FillInBlankComponent) private fill: FillComponent;
  @ViewChild(InfoComponent) private info: InfoComponent;
  public title: string;

  constructor(public dataService: DataService, public shared: SharedService) {
    this.dataService.get().subscribe(data => {
      const d = this.dataService.convert(data, 2);

      this.title = d[0];

    });
  }
```

Till now everything works fine.

But the problem is here, in InfoComponent, when I try to get data it gives me empty result.

```
@Injectable()
  export class InfoComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public title: string;

  constructor(public shared: SharedService) {

   this.title = this.shared.getUrlHistoryObj();

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('i am title from info and i am boos')
    console.log(this.title)
}
}
```

I guess the problem is in asynchronous loading. How could I fix it?

Comment: Move  this.shared.setData(this.title);  to the constractor  from ngOnint and tell me please if it worked?

Comment: @Vega 7 I tried this before, but in this case it doesn't even set the data - set

Comment: Ensure that you provide `SharedService` online in `@NgModule(....)` of `AppComponent`. If you provide it on a `@Component()` this leads to as many instances of the service as there are instances of the component. To me it looks like you're sending from one instance and subscribing on another and therefore receiving nothing - just a guess based on the limited information provided.

Comment: You probably need to use @Input setter

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it is in providers in AppComponent in NgModule

Comment: Why is the Info component injectable? A component is a component and just a component, should have @component instead

Answer (score 0):

On info component, move this line outside the constructor, to the ngOnInit:

> this.title = this.shared.getUrlHistoryObj();

Comment: What's the output you get? An empty string or undefined?

Comment: it is empty string